# Is there a function that, when given a set of data points, would move those data points towards some other defined point?

Tags: functions

This question is ultimately related to salary equity; if this is best fit at Quant.SE I would understand.

Imagine we have the following data points: 30, 80, 150, 300. Is there a function that would "press" those data points towards a defined central point such that the change in each data point is correlated with its distance from that central point?

In other words, if I want these data points to converge towards 120, 150 would change the least since it's the closest to 120; meanwhile, 300 would change the most since it's the farthest from 120. I could envision there might also be some sort of coefficient variable that could determine the amount/severity of convergence.

Is there a function/principle/etc. that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. The simplest example is the linear function.

Let $x_0$ be the "defined central point" and $\lambda$ be the "severity of convergence" parameter, so that $\lambda=0$ means no change and $\lambda=1$ means that every value is just sent to $x_0$. Then
$$ f(x) = \lambda \cdot x_0 + (1-\lambda)\cdot x $$
has the desired properties.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, and the two variables allow me the considerable experimentation I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why (1−)⋅ at the end and not just ? I see that it accounts for data above the central point, but my brain is somehow missing the logic of it.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's above or below. Try experimenting with and without $(1-\lambda)$ with many different $x$ simultaneously (especially those much greater or much smaller than $x_0$), and you'll see.